# What is wrong with the routing of my HTML/CSS files for various locations on Nginx?

Tags: html, css, nginx

I have implemented flask app in gunicorn and it is currently running on Nginx. The structure of the app is as follows: several HTML pages in folder `templates` (index.html, chat.html, token.html), folder with CSS files in `static`.

What I want is to be sure that when users access `host:port` they see `index.html`, but when they access `host:port/token` they see `token.html`.

I am pretty sure the problem is in my Nginx configuration. I could have managed to make `index.html` appear once the website is accessed. CSS files are used as well, since html page does not look plain (so there is no problem with accessing CSS files here).

However, once I am accessing `host:port/token`, the page becomes blank HTML code, which is found in `token.html`. For some reason, information in CSS files is not applied to HTML in this case.

How can I make Nginx find my CSS files? Should I somehow specify location of folder with static files? But it works fine for the normal location (`host:port`), just does not work for a different one. My Nginx configuration is below:

```
server {

listen 7000 ssl http2 default_server;
listen [::]:7000 ssl http2 default_server;

server_name host www.host;

access_log /home/user/project/server/nginx_logs/nginx-access.log;
error_log  /home/user/project/nginx_logs/nginx-error.log;

include snippets/certs.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/server/chat.sock;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            }

location /token {
    index token.html;
    alias /home/user/project/server/app/templates;
} }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding on how the flask app is run under wsgi server and not fully understand the effect of `try_files` redirect. For a flask app, `index.html` in `template/` is generated based on flask route you setup, and it is a template, not a static html file per se. So assuming you setup the wsgi server correctly to run the flask app, then the following nginx configuration is all it required to run the flask app:

```
server {

    listen 7000 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:7000 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name host www.host;
    root /home/user/project/app;

    access_log /home/user/project/server/nginx_logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log  /home/user/project/nginx_logs/nginx-error.log;

    include snippets/certs.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/project/server/chat.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

This configuration basically pass all the requests that hitting the root to the backend wsgi socket (which running your flask app). It works, however it is not ideal, first, if you check the access log, you will noticed that nginx logs every GET request including GET requests for those static contents located in `static/` directory. secondly, you probably want nginx to handle those static contents directly without passing it to the backend. Therefore you often see nginx configuration for flask app have at least one extra location directive to handle the static content:

```
server {
    ### all the directives as previous example ###

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/user/project/app/static/;
    }

    location / {
        ### as per previous example ###
    }
```

}